# How to flag non-consecutive numbers in R with doubles present

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm wondering how I might flag all non-consecutive numbers in a column using R. Specifically, and unlike this question,  [How to flag non-sequential numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253559/how-to-flag-non-sequential-numbers-in-r) which is similar, I would like to flag the number AFTER the non-consecutive number.

Additionally, I need the repeated numbers in the column to NOT get flagged.

Here is an example below. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
x <- data.frame(hour = c(1,2,3,5,6,6,7,9,10,11,11,1,5,6,10,11,20,2,3))

        hour
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     5
5     6
6     6
7     7
8     9
9    10
10   11
11   11
12    1
13    5
14    6
15    10
16    11
17    20
18    2
19    3
```

I am hoping to end up with something like this:

```
    hour flag
1     1    0
2     2    0
3     3    0
4     5    1
5     6    0
6     6    0
7     7    0
8     9    1
9    10    0
10   11    0
11   11    0
12    1    1
13    5    1
14    6    0
15    10   1
16    11   0
17    20   1
18     2   1
19     3   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way:

```
library(dplyr)

x |> mutate(flag = c(0, abs(diff(hour)) > 1))
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer, however, perhaps I didn't make the greatest example, I have numbers that don't move sequentially larger as they go. I have updated to show you what I mean! Your answer didn't flag those that move, from say, 11 >1 or 20 >2. I gave a poor example!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `lag`:

```r
x |>
  mutate(flag = +!(hour - lag(hour, default = F)) %in% 0:1)
```

Comment: Hi thank you! This answer ended up flagging the doubles though

Comment: @fishlakeslimno whoops! sorry missed that; updated my answer. Though I would say `diff` is the way to go here.